# Spacebar "Hand" tool affected by its own grid in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, tools, cc-2019

There is something about the spacebar "Hand" tool that I never noticed before.

It may sound ultra picky, but when it's at max zoom, you can see that this tool follows a pattern which I never noticed before, nor I remember seeing it.

I don't know if I toggled something (that's not snap to grid neither in Transform nor View) but I remember it being super fluid, no matter how zoomed in I was. Now that I'm aware of that "invisible grid" it feels extremely choppy and annoying.

Is there a way to disable this? Or has it been always there, and I just never noticed it before?

[image: The pattern highlighted with guides]

I'm using Illustrator CS6.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't replicate the problem at all. I see no difference between the behaviour of the Hand tool at any zoom level.

Comment: @BillyKerr you may be using a newer version of Illustrator, which has some smooth zoom features etc.

Comment: @WELZ - I'm using the latest CC version, which does indeed have GPU acceleration with animated zoom, however even when switching those features off. it still doesn't cause the effect the OP describes.  This might be something which has been fixed in the latest release.

Comment: I posted a Gif of how it looks like in real time.

Comment: Are you using a graphic tablet besides the mouse?

Comment: this looks like a bug or some performance issue caused by hardware, can we close this as off-topic?

Comment: @Luciano oh I completely forgot about this, but the issue persisted through these two years haha. I have moved to CC 2017. I will update you guys tomorrow with the new suggestions, both in my CC and CS6 installations.

Comment: @Cristóbal Did you get around to test? Did any of the solutions solve your problem?

Comment: @2rB nope. None of them worked, but the issue it's not present in CC 2017. No mater how much I zoom using spacebar to move around the canvas is as smooth as it should be. Maybe it's an issue for the CS versions. Anyhow, I'm not using CS6 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by "Pixel preview".
Switching it off, and you should be able to position the document however you would want to.

[image: Illustrator View menu]

Pixel preview is used for previewing image pixels so that you can get an idea on what it will look like when exporting as a raster graphic (e.g. for use as JPEG / PNG on the web). In this mode you will see individual pixels instead of the vectors.

When you zoom in a lot Illustrator will also show a pixel grid if pixel preview is turned on.

Comment: I will check tomorrow!

Comment: Sorry for the super late answer. That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It can essentially only move 1 pixel at a time.

At a normal viewing size, (on an hd monitor) moving 1 pixel at a time will look very smooth.

When you are zoomed that much, one pixel will occupy a large portion of your screen, which causes the appearance of choppiness.

---

I don't see that actual grid which you are seeing, not sure about that.

Comment: Well, I remember it being fluid no matter how zoomed it was. Is it always been like this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure... You may have never actually zoomed in all the way to the max (6.4k on cs6) because at 3.2k it doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: It's actually at 6400. Look at the bottom left corner.

Comment: @Cristóbal yes, 6.4k = 6,400

Comment: Do you have whole pixel transform switched to on? If so...

Comment: @GerardFalla I'm not sure what pixel transform is. But I have moved to CC 2017, and the issue stated here it's not present in this Illustrator version. I guess it's a problem for the CS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with others on this. Not seeing any variation even at 6400% -- and in CS6.. it's always smooth.

Now having *artwork* which may cause some delay in **screen redraw** *could* be the difference. CS6 (well any version) can start to lag a tad the more complex art is.

Comment: Sorry for the super late answer. Got to do some tests.
Started a new empty document and the issue persists.